# Let $z = a + b*i$ where we assume a and b are real numbers. Prove $e^{-z} = \frac{1}{e^{z}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the easiest way to prove that $e^{-z} = \frac{1}{e^{z}}$ when $z = a + b*i$ where we assume a and b are real numbers.

Comment: What is there even to prove? Maybe using the same properties for real numbers? $e^{-z} = e^{-a - bi} = e^{-a} \ \cdot \ e^{-bi} = 1/e^a 1/e^{bi} = 1/e^{a+bi} = 1/e^z$

Comment: How are you defining $e^z$?

Comment: That's why I am unsure about what to do as the teacher just handed us a few equations with complex numbers and asked us to come up with an example as to why its either true or false.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) three options, depending on how you're defining $e^z$:

(1) If you define $e^{a + bi} = e^a (\cos b + i \sin b)$, then it follows just from algebraic manipulation and the corresponding real result.

(2) If you define $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$, then the result follows with some more algebraic manipulation, probably along with some sort of result about uniform convergence on compact sets.

(3) A better definition is to take $e^z$ to be the unique solution of the differential equation $f' = f$ with $f(0) = 1$. Then for fixed $w$, the function $g(z) = e^{z + w} / e^w$ satisfies the same equation and boundary condition, so we have $e^{z + w} = e^z e^w$ everywhere. This approach requires results on the existence and uniqueness of certain differential equations, though.

Comment: Number (2) does not require anything as sophisticated as that....$ e^ze^{-z}=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(z)f_n(-z),$ where $f_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n z^j/j!. $..... Expand $f_n(z)f_n(-z)$ into one polynomial $g_n(z)$, and use the Binomial Theorem to show that the  co-efficient of $z^k$ in $g_n(z)$ is $0$ for $1\leq k\leq n,$ and make a crude but sufficient upper bound for  the sum of the moduli of the terms in $g_n(z)$ of degree $>n.$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the argument I was describing, except for dealing with a general product $e^z e^w$.